# Pop up box - how to handle it in selenium

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors

I have been attempting to click the confirm logout button for so long and I can not get it to work! I have a test that is supposed to log you out and return to the homepage as soon as it exits, but I cant seem to click the button. When I attempt to switch to the pop up frame using

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

It runs and does not give me any errors... however I can not get it to locate the confirm logout!
[image: popup box]

[image: This is the pop up boxes id]

[image: This is the sign out button tag]

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem and solved it by searching the frame with XPATH. Maybe this snippet helps you out:

```
wd = your WebDriver; 
searchFrame= wd.findElement(By.xpath("whatever"));
wd.switchTo().frame(searchFrame);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("button2")));
wd.findElement(By.className("button2")).click();
```

Comment: the By.className, what is that?

Comment: `By`is using to define with which type you search for an element.

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with By, but I dont understand what the .className is looking for..

Comment: Did you google "C# selenium By.className"? You can probably find the answer there.

Comment: @JeffC C#? It's tagged as java.

Comment: @alecxe oops... brought the language from another question to this one... still my question is valid, just have to swap C# with java... it's still a very easy question to google and find the answer.

Comment: @Tree55Topz forget the className - its not important. for your case like the "button2".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the HTML code for the iframe, but, given what we have, we can locate the iframe that contains the provided log out button:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement("//iframe[.//a[contains(@id, 'confirmLogoutDialog')]]");
driver.switchTo.frame(frame);
```

Then, you may locate your button by link text and click it:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
```

You may also need to wait for it to become clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement logout = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Sign Out")));
logout.click();
```

Comment: I am now getting a no such frame: element is not a frame error

Comment: @Tree55Topz okay, fixed.

Comment: I am now getting a stale element reference error.. What is wrong with this stupid pop up box!!! And thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tree55Topz need more information here: provide the complete HTML of the page including the popup box and it's iframe. Also, what code you have so far and the traceback of the error you are currently getting. Thanks.